# odd spacing between bars in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this stacked bar chart and it seems to make these non-even gaps every number of bars, it disappears when the number of bars is low but it gets worst when the number is large and it also not fixed in one location but it changes according to the screen size, you can see the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kamel3d/bh78odsf/) 
or on my website [there](https://www.menacorona,com)
[image]

```
    var seriesColors = [
                                        '#fb6e4c',
                                        '#5f7aec',
                                        '#fde46f',
                                        '#6cb8f4',
                                        '#8ee4a0',
                                        '#e373f7'
                                        ];    

                var chart = new Highcharts.chart('mychart', {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'column',
                        spacingLeft: 35,
                        // plotBackgroundColor: '#bcbcbc',
                        marginBottom: 60,
                     },
                    title: false,
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ["  1 مارس 2020","  2 مارس 2020","  3 مارس 2020","  4 مارس 2020","  5 مارس 2020","  6 مارس 2020","  7 مارس 2020","  8 مارس 2020","  9 مارس 2020","  10 مارس 2020","  11 مارس 2020","  12 مارس 2020","  13 مارس 2020","  14 مارس 2020","  15 مارس 2020","  16 مارس 2020","  17 مارس 2020","  18 مارس 2020","  19 مارس 2020","  20 مارس 2020","  21 مارس 2020","  22 مارس 2020","  23 مارس 2020","  24 مارس 2020","  25 مارس 2020","  26 مارس 2020","  27 مارس 2020","  28 مارس 2020","  29 مارس 2020","  30 مارس 2020","  31 مارس 2020","  1 أبريل 2020","  2 أبريل 2020","  3 أبريل 2020","  4 أبريل 2020","  5 أبريل 2020","  6 أبريل 2020","  7 أبريل 2020","  8 أبريل 2020","  9 أبريل 2020","  10 أبريل 2020","  11 أبريل 2020","  12 أبريل 2020","  13 أبريل 2020","  14 أبريل 2020","  15 أبريل 2020","  16 أبريل 2020","  17 أبريل 2020","  18 أبريل 2020","  19 أبريل 2020","  20 أبريل 2020","  21 أبريل 2020","  22 أبريل 2020","  23 أبريل 2020","  24 أبريل 2020","  25 أبريل 2020","  26 أبريل 2020","  27 أبريل 2020","  28 أبريل 2020","  29 أبريل 2020","  30 أبريل 2020","  1 مايو 2020","  2 مايو 2020","  3 مايو 2020","  4 مايو 2020","  5 مايو 2020","  6 مايو 2020","  7 مايو 2020","  8 مايو 2020","  9 مايو 2020","  10 مايو 2020","  11 مايو 2020","  12 مايو 2020","  13 مايو 2020","  14 مايو 2020","  15 مايو 2020","  16 مايو 2020","  17 مايو 2020","  18 مايو 2020","  19 مايو 2020","  20 مايو 2020","  21 مايو 2020","  22 مايو 2020","  23 مايو 2020","  24 مايو 2020","  25 مايو 2020","  26 مايو 2020","  27 مايو 2020","  28 مايو 2020","  29 مايو 2020","  30 مايو 2020","  31 مايو 2020","  1 يونيو 2020","  2 يونيو 2020","  3 يونيو 2020","  4 يونيو 2020","  5 يونيو 2020","  6 يونيو 2020","  7 يونيو 2020","  8 يونيو 2020","  9 يونيو 2020","  10 يونيو 2020","  11 يونيو 2020","  12 يونيو 2020","  13 يونيو 2020","  14 يونيو 2020","  15 يونيو 2020","  16 يونيو 2020","  17 يونيو 2020",],
                        labels:{
                                useHTML:true,
                                formatter:function(){return '<span class="xlabel">' + this.value + '</span>';},
                                enabled:true,//default is true,
                                step: 15,
                               // rotation: -90,
                                // style: {
                                //     color: '#eb583b',
                                //     font: "'DroidArabicNaskhRegular','Lato','Helvetica Neue'",
                                //     fontSize: '20px',
                                //     rtl: true,
                                //     },
                                 },
                        //       itemStyle: {
                        //     color: '#6c757d',
                        //     fontSize: '15px',
                        //     fontFamily: "'DroidArabicNaskhRegular','Lato','Helvetica Neue'",
                        //     // direction: 'rtl'
                        //                 },

                    },
                    yAxis: {


                        labels:{
                            format:"{value:,.0f}"

                        },
                        opposite: true,
                        min: 0,
                        title: false,
                        stackLabels: {
                            enabled: false,
                            style: {
                                fontFamily: "'DroidArabicNaskhRegular','Lato','Helvetica Neue'",
                                fontWeight: 'bold',
                                color: ( // theme
                                    Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style &&
                                    Highcharts.defaultOptions.title.style.color
                                ) || 'gray'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        align: 'center',
                        x: 0,
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        y: -10,
                        floating: false,
                        backgroundColor: Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || 'white',
                        rtl: true,
                        borderColor: '#CCC',
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        shadow: false,
                        itemStyle: {
                            color: '#6c757d',
                            fontSize: '15px',
                            fontFamily: "'DroidArabicNaskhRegular','Lato','Helvetica Neue'",
                            // direction: 'rtl'
                        },

                    },
                    tooltip: {   
                        borderColor:'grey',                  
                        shared: true,
                        useHTML: true,
                        style: {fontFamily: "'DroidArabicNaskhRegular','Lato','Helvetica Neue'"},
                        // headerFormat: '<b><span class="tooltiphead">{point.x}</span></b>',
                        //  pointFormat: '<br/>{point.y:,.0f} :{series.name}',
                        //  footerFormat: '</br><span>{point.stackTotal:,.0f} :الإجمالي</span>'
                         formatter: function() {
                            var s = '<b><span class="tooltiphead">'+ this.x +'</span></b>';
                            sum = 0;
                            $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
                            s += '<br/>'+ point.series.name + ':  '+ numberWithCommas(point.y) +' <i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true" style="color:'+ point.color +';"></i>';
                            sum += point.y;
                                });
                                s += '<br/><b>الإجمالي: '+ numberWithCommas(sum)+'</b>'
                            return s;
                        },
                    },
                    plotOptions: {

                        column: {
                            // pointPadding: 0,
                            // borderWidth: 0,
                            // groupPadding: 0,
                            // shadow: false,
                            maxPointWidth: 50,
                            stacking: 'normal',
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                        },
                        series: {// this i snot working you can delete it is you come back later 
                            pointPlacement:'between',
                                grouping: false,
                                // pointWidth:9.5,
                                groupPadding: 0,
                                pointPadding: 0.12,
                                borderWidth: 0,
                                animation: false,
                                states: {
                                        hover:{
                                            // color: '#bcbcbc',
                                        },
                                        inactive: {
                                                        enabled: true,
                                                        opacity: 0.5
                                                  }
                                     },

                                },

                    },
                    series: [
                     {
                        name: 'أمريكا الشمالية',
                        data: [1600,1376,1866,1234,1281,2043,1747,1221,875,1195,1760,1567,1581,1916,1940,1630,2020,1999,2368,2364,2731,3186,3098,3722,5381,5490,7058,7352,7346,7001,8789,8545,9287,8646,8945,9324,10646,9481,9573,10316,11347,11893,11671,11828,11131,11452,12746,12805,11946,13001,12500,14228,11946,13577,13141,12266,11585,11505,11437,12531,13080,13454,12037,12910,14026,14353,16734,14588,16332,16083,17859,16089,18346,17721,18079,20507,18580,20217,20941,21890,22289,23821,25110,23981,24292,22219,20086,23277,25056,29193,27037,29279,26993,30444,32656,33103,32132,34318,34793,35873,31253,33154,37926,37140,39329,38987,39512,37157,37330,],
                       color: seriesColors[0]
                    }, {           
                        name: 'أوروبا',
                        data: [737,527,629,979,1401,1775,2137,2544,2782,3405,5059,7410,7433,8189,8383,10754,11123,13635,18360,20475,21446,19083,25434,23619,29674,34985,35590,36517,29442,30888,35147,36524,35560,37105,33515,29825,27118,29006,34532,33346,38600,30544,52732,25738,26085,31304,43302,32784,23983,35559,24326,26815,26674,29006,25403,26027,23139,23518,23099,21547,23762,23687,24624,22495,21623,23081,28696,26725,25694,22499,21522,24137,21931,19808,21099,21380,18715,18252,16699,18441,15417,17602,19788,17827,15741,14566,18225,15184,20382,17077,17337,15604,14113,14735,20582,15995,16873,16805,15669,14885,14468,14928,14351,15486,16241,15477,15050,13612,15122,],
                       color: seriesColors[1]
                    },{
                        name: 'آسيا',
                        data: [1,4,3,10,3,19,0,40,8,13,15,28,35,78,61,89,84,122,182,205,221,288,401,467,540,577,583,391,561,470,620,633,701,906,698,733,706,666,804,830,691,725,867,797,973,954,1187,1427,1320,1227,1173,1097,1417,1452,1735,1262,1555,1335,1686,2017,2092,1752,2203,1646,2695,2091,2547,2607,3805,2861,2767,3033,3207,2988,3029,2929,3432,3018,3699,3358,3761,4798,4161,3875,4131,4106,3590,5291,4749,5957,6225,5195,5943,4931,5147,7198,7154,6659,6122,6882,6882,6530,6489,7255,8255,8105,8838,9636,7367,],
                       color: seriesColors[2]
                    },{
                        name: 'أمريكا الجنوبية',
                        data: [12,27,23,37,74,63,143,134,88,377,368,517,525,598,887,1356,1902,1594,6248,5839,6902,8214,11394,10922,12725,19211,19209,21287,20332,22705,27783,26943,32659,33490,34314,31284,31028,32825,33632,37139,35997,32044,30553,27526,29065,31232,34804,35423,35247,28798,29093,29993,32364,32318,39665,35776,30714,25379,27386,30855,33181,38110,33058,29999,25865,27126,28912,32001,31014,29716,23475,21875,25245,24903,31687,29668,29276,22776,26042,25427,27287,30510,29148,27443,26055,23857,24691,24056,28123,29953,29593,25651,25744,26684,25838,27771,31203,28815,29453,22709,24039,24075,26152,30719,33289,33031,24878,27213,31420,],
                       color: seriesColors[3]
                    },{
                        name: 'إفريقيا',
                        data: [6,0,3,5,6,12,11,22,7,22,33,84,89,63,67,237,283,243,474,621,717,1136,814,854,828,1113,1183,1281,1029,1003,2196,2385,2300,2027,2333,1913,2021,2866,5084,4112,5372,2828,2900,4074,3066,5195,4351,5302,5109,4515,4206,4777,5353,7427,17398,10052,6881,6942,10395,10612,12491,11626,10248,12072,12093,12953,16469,15294,16975,14763,12064,10704,15526,20069,21222,25685,21820,15279,20928,26634,30742,29310,30521,26723,26479,23060,28239,34345,38883,39636,48036,32190,26093,36557,46168,43126,44566,39691,33093,27771,29710,42593,48087,45761,42397,32323,33546,36850,51142,],
                       color: seriesColors[4]
                    }, {
                        name: 'أوقيانوسيا',
                        data: [2,3,9,15,3,7,4,13,15,16,21,34,41,51,49,80,79,124,127,127,299,532,138,425,375,529,419,580,407,458,257,365,347,287,308,228,181,158,169,127,152,117,32,58,81,45,43,68,59,51,24,27,15,15,20,26,20,10,26,11,17,19,23,25,25,32,20,20,7,23,12,22,10,11,31,16,10,10,14,8,9,15,4,15,5,12,16,11,16,19,8,10,20,8,11,7,5,8,6,2,5,3,9,9,5,12,18,15,14,],
                       color: seriesColors[5]
                    }]
                },
                function(chart){// this function is not working as intended yet 
                        $(chart.series).each(function(i, serie){
                                serie.legendItem.on('mouseover', function(){
                                    console.log('mouse in');

                                }).on('mouseout', function(){
                                    console.log('mouse out');

                                })
                        });

} );function numberWithCommas(x) { return x.toString().replace(/\B(?<!\.\d*)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is a consequence of Highcharts rounding off the positions all
>   columns to full pixel in order for them to render crisp on the
>   monitor. If the x position were not rounded, the edges would become
>   unsharp.

For more information please see this issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2690

As a solution disable `crisp` option:

```
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            ...,
            crisp: false
        },
        ...
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/brheq08z/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.crisp